# How do I override views-view-summary-unformatted.tpl.php inside my own theme?

Tags: views

I cannot override views-view-summary-unformatted.tpl.php inside my own theme. I copy the tpl from the views module directory, paste into my theme directory and modify the code. My website will not recognize the new tpl. If I make the changes directly inside the views module, then I can see my changes on my website. However, I know it is not best practice to hack a contributed module. I've tried adding "--myViewName" to the tpl file, but this doesn't help. When I look at the Theme Information in my view, I don't see views-view-summary-unformatted.tpl.php listed there. (The reason I am trying to override this tpl is that I want my alpha bar to include all letters of the alphabet even if there are no entries for a particular letter.) Can someone please help me figure out what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I know, I know how it sounds, but have you cleared your caches? Especially theme registry? And ahve you clicked "rescan" in view's settings? Copying .tpl.php files from module to your theme is **not** considered hacking. It is the proper way. And it should work, if you **keep the name just as it was**. Especially, count `-` signs, sometimes they are doubled `--`, and once I even seen them tripled `---`. Using wrong number will stop Drupal from recognizing them.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, I did clear the caches and theme registry. Yes, I did rescan, but views-view-summary-unformatted.tpl.php never even showed up as an option at all. And by hacking, I meant if I change the tpl file inside the views directory (because it works there). And yes, I tried keeping the same exact name. Is there anything else I might be missing?

Comment: Unfortunately no, nothing comes to my mind. It is that irritating case of "works for me", I'm afraid.

Comment: Should I be using a different template to affect the alphabetical menu? Here are my options under theme information. (BTW I am using views 3.7) Display output: views-view.tpl.php, views-view--clone-of-glossary.tpl.php, views-view--default.tpl.php, views-view--default.tpl.php, views-view--attachment.tpl.php, views-view--clone-of-glossary--attachment.tpl.php
Style output: views-view-table.tpl.php, views-view-table--clone-of-glossary.tpl.php, views-view-table--default.tpl.php, views-view-table--default.tpl.php, views-view-table--attachment.tpl.php, views-view-table--clone-of-glossary--attachment.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but today I struggled with this and thought I should provide a solution.

First, you have to rename your copy of 'views-view-summary-unformatted.tpl.php' so views can discover it. It should be named **'views-view-summary-unformatted--my-view.tpl.php'**.

You then need to click the **'rescan template files'** button under the theme information in the view.